# How I can fetch latest data from my sql as per recent date or id

Tags: mysql

How to I get latest data from this query, actually the table is hudge we need recent data from past 2 year, how can I modify my  query accordigly.

select stagingScriptDB.*, testBedSuiteMapping.template from stagingScriptDB inner join testBedSuiteMapping on testBedSuiteMapping.id = stagingScriptDB.idScriptDB limit 10;

Comment: Read up on `ORDER BY`

Comment: can you share database structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you shared the table structure it will be good.

we can use this query type to retrieve last record for id

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT max(ID) FROM table_name
  GROUP BY column_name
  ORDER BY column_name
)
```